# Connecting to Oracle DB from IIS. Error: The underlying provider failed on Open

Tags: c#, oracle, wcf, iis

I get the following error when attempting to consume a WCF Service hosted in IIS 8.5. `The underlying provider failed on Open.` I am using an `Oracle DB 11G`.

From my development environment, I am able to connect to `Oracle DB` with no issues. If I simply Run the WCF Service within Visual Studio and run the Client Application. I am also able to Connect to the Oracle Instance from within `Visual Studio` and consume the service.

I am not sure where to look. Finally, I turned off Firewall on the Development Server just to see if there was any issues. I am also able to Ping the Oracle Server with success.

Here is the Connection String from IIS:

```
metadata=res://*/OracleDB.csdl|res://*/OracleDB.ssdl|res://*/OracleDB.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
provider connection string="DATA SOURCE=INSTANCE_TNSNAMES;PASSWORD=MyPassword;
PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=MyUserID"
```

This is the connection string added to the application via Nuget when Oracle Managed Drivers are installed in Visual Studio and it is the same string in the application.

Update: Here is a list of things I tried:

Things I have tried:

1. Installed Oracle Instant Client on the Windows Server running IIS
2. Create TNS_ADMIN variable in Environment Variable
3. Set Path to Oracle Instant Client
4. Add (install) ODBC drivers to the instant client folder
5. Create and configured tnsnames.ora

Still getting the same error:

Comment: on the server hosting IIS do you have the right version of Oracle Client installed, with the right TNS Names?

Comment: IIS is installed and running on Windows Server 2012 R2. Do I need to installed Oracle client on this server?

Comment: yes, the oracle client will need installing on this server too,  you will need to ensure that the oracle client is the same as what you have been testing with and the TNSNames file and any other file that is on your test machine is on the server too.

Comment: Simon: I installed the Instant Client as indicated in my updated question. The only difference is, on the dev computer I installed the full client. ODAC.

Comment: have you done the same with the server?

Comment: Not sure I am following: I installed Oracle Instant Client on the Server running IIS. However, the Developer Computer has the Full Oracle Client (ODAC) Components. I was under the impression that the Instant client would be enough and that I did not need to install the full client.

Comment: the client 'should' be enough, however in my experience it isnt always...  go into your control panel, admin tools and check that you are connecting correctly using the ODBC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server running IIS, will need to have Oracle Client installed and the TNSNames file and each other file that you have in your test system will need to match that of the webserver you are using.

you should where possible use the same oracle client version as in each system.

Comment: As much as I hate installing unnecessary files, I simply deleted the `Instant Client` and installed the full `ODAC` components found here: `http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html`. I unchecked the Components for Visual Studio.

Now it is working.

Comment: Yes, you mentioned a very important info in your post:
`The client 'should' be enough, however in my experience it isn't always.`
It was the reason I decided to just installed the full client. Thank you so much.